# Buttons linked to functions not working in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that is linked to an event listener. When the button is clicked, it is supposed to change the text of a paragraph from 'Hello' to a confirmation message. However, when I click the button, nothing happens. I checked the console log, but there aren't any errors. The script is contained in the head (in a  tag), while the paragraph and button is contained in the body.

The function:

```
document.getElementById("sendForm").addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("formMessage").innerHTML = "Thank you for your feedback! We'll try to respond to your message promptly.";
});
```

The button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="sendForm">
```

The location that is supposed to be changed:

```
<p id="formMessage">Hello</p>
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. Please ensure you have provided a a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: submit buttons submit if it is in a form....

Comment: If the script is in the head, then it is running BEFORE the element is added to the page meaning there should be an error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If  the input tag is inside a form tag, the button is meant to submit the form so basically the page reloads after submission. In such a case you prevent the default action of the element like so. Also if the script is inside the head tag make sure it is wrapped by a window.onload function so the bindings are set after the window is loaded.

```
 window.onload = function(){
           document.getElementById("sendForm").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           document.getElementById("formMessage").innerHTML = "Thank you for your feedback! We'll try to respond to your message promptly.";
        });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's some HTML wisdom: Use the 'button' tag it will make your life a WHOLE lot easier.

```
 <button onclick="func()">Hello</button>

 function func()
 {
    document.getElementById("formMessage").innerHTML = "Thank you for your feedback! We'll try to respond to your message promptly.";
 }
```

I just noticed you are using a "submit" input. You can also do this if you are using a form:

```
 <form onsubmit="func()">
   <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
 </form>

 function func()
 {
    document.getElementById("formMessage").innerHTML = "Thank you for your feedback! We'll try to respond to your message promptly.";
 }
```

It also could be because of inproper placement  of the "addeventlistener" line. If that line runs before the DOM is loaded it won't work. I recommend adding one of these to your application:

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
   document.getElementById("sendForm").addEventListener("click", func());
 });
```

OR

```
<body onload="functionYouWantToCallOncePageIsLoaded()">
```